# Nullglob breaks array declaration printing

Tags: arrays, bash, glob, shopt

On GNU bash, version 3.2.57, I am seeing a conflict between using `declare` to print an array variable and the `nullglob` option.

These two seem to me to be very unrelated, but is this intentional when `nullglob` is enabled?

```
#!/bin/bash

test () {
  local FOO="xyz"
  local BAR=("one" "two" "three")
  declare -p FOO
  declare -a -p BAR
}

echo $(test)
shopt -s nullglob
echo $(test)
shopt -u nullglob
echo $(test)
```

Output:

```
declare -- FOO="xyz" declare -a BAR='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")'
declare -- FOO="xyz" declare -a
declare -- FOO="xyz" declare -a BAR='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")'
```

Note on the middle line, when `nullglob` is set, no declaration for `BAR` is emitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not `nullglob` but not quoting the `echo` command.

If you quote it then it should work fine:

```
shopt -s nullglob
echo "$(test)"
declare -- FOO="xyz"
declare -a BAR='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")'
```

Without quoting shell is attempting to expand the output of `test` function as there are many glob characters in the output.

When `nullglob` is set then expansion fails and nothing is printed for failed glob expression.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I didn't realize I need to quote `$()`. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when it allows me to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By not quoting the `echo $(test)` then `$(test)` part is subject to pathname expansion. The result of `declare -p` contains `[]` chars which are checked against the filesystem. When nullglob is set and there are no matching files, then the word is removed.

Try setting `shopt -s failglob` to see what's happening in more detail; the lack of matching files will cause an error.